# How can I insert records which have dicts and lists in Flask Eve?

Tags: python, flask, eve

I'm using Flask-Eve to provide an API for my data. I would like to insert my records using Eve, so that I get a _created attribute and the other Eve-added attributes.

Two of my fields are dicts, and one is a list. When I try to insert that to Eve the structure seems to get flattened, losing some information. Trying to tell Eve about the dict & list elements gives me an error on POST, saying those fields need to be dicts and lists, but they already are! Please can someone help me & tell me what I'm doing wrong?

My Eve conf looked like this:

```
'myendpoint': { 'allow_unknown': True,
                   'schema': { 'JobTitle': { 'type':       'string',
                                             'required':       True,
                                             'empty':         False,
                                             'minlength':         3,
                                             'maxlength':        99 },
                                'JobDescription': { 'type': 'string',
                                                    'required':       True,
                                                    'empty':         False,
                                                    'minlength':        32,
                                                    'maxlength':        102400 },
                           },
               },
```

But when I POST the following structure using requests:

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("56e840686dbf9a5fe069220e"),
        "Salary" : {
                "OtherPay" : "On Application"
        },
        "ContactPhone" : "xx",
        "JobTypeCodeList" : [
                "Public Sector",
                "Other"
        ],
        "CompanyName" : "Scc",
        "url" : "xx",
        "JobTitle" : "xxx",
        "WebAdID" : "TA7494725_1_1",
        "JobDescription" : "xxxx",
        "JobLocation" : {
                "DisplayCity" : "BRIDGWATER",
                "City" : "BRIDGWATER",
                "StateProvince" : "Somerset",
                "Country" : "UK",
                "PostalCode" : "TA6"
        },
        "CustomField1" : "Permanent",
        "CustomField3" : "FTJOBUKNCSG",
        "WebAdManagerEmail" : "xxxx",
        "JobType" : "Full",
        "ProductID" : "JCPRI0UK"
}
```

The post line looks like this:

```
resp = requests.post(url, data = job)
```

It gets 'flattened' and loses the information from the dicts and list:

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("56e83f5a6dbf9a6395ea559d"),
        "Salary" : "OtherPay",
        "_updated" : ISODate("2016-03-15T16:59:06Z"),
        "ContactPhone" : "xx",
        "JobTypeCodeList" : "Public Sector",
        "CompanyName" : "Scc",
        "url" : "xxx",
        "JobTitle" : "xx",
        "WebAdID" : "TA7494725_1_1",
        "JobDescription" : "xxx",
        "JobLocation" : "DisplayCity",
        "CustomField1" : "Permanent",
        "_created" : ISODate("2016-03-15T16:59:06Z"),
        "CustomField3" : "FTJOBUKNCSG",
        "_etag" : "55d8d394141652f5dc2892a900aa450403a63d10",
        "JobType" : "Full",
        "ProductID" : "JCPRI0UK"
}
```

I've tried updating my schema to say some are dicts and lists:

```
     'JobTypeCodeList': { 'type': 'list'},
     'Salary':          { 'type': 'dict'},
     'JobLocation':     { 'type': 'dict'},
```

But then when I POST in the new record I get an error saying

```
 {u'Salary': u'must be of dict type', u'JobTypeCodeList': u'must be of list type', u'JobLocation': u'must be of dict type'},
```

I've verified before the POST that `type(job.Salary) == dict` etc, so I'm not sure how to resolve this. While I can POST the record directly into MongoDB ok, bypassing Eve, I'd prefer to use Eve if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case this is useful to anyone else, I ended up working around this issue by posting a flat structure into Eve, and then using the on_insert and on_update events to loop through the keys and construct objects (and lists) from them.

It's a bit convoluted but it does the trick and now that it's in place it's fairly transparent to use. My objects added to MongoDB through Eve now have embedded lists and hashes, but they also get the handy Eve attributes like _created and _updated, while the POST and PATCH requests also get validated through Eve's normal schema.

The only really awkward thing is that on_insert and on_update send slightly different arguments, so there's a lot of repetition in the code below which I haven't yet refactored out.

Any characters can be used as flags: I'm using two underscores to indicate key/values which should end up as a single object, and two ampersands for values which should be split into a list. The structure I'm posting in now looks like this:

```
    "Salary__OtherPay" : "On Application"
    "ContactPhone" : "xx",
    "JobTypeCodeList" : "Public Sector&&Other",
    "CompanyName" : "Scc",
    "url" : "xx",
    "JobTitle" : "xxx",
    "WebAdID" : "TA7494725_1_1",
    "JobDescription" : "xxxx",
    "JobLocation__DisplayCity" : "BRIDGWATER",
    "JobLocation__City" : "BRIDGWATER",
    "JobLocation__StateProvince" : "Somerset",
    "JobLocation__Country" : "UK",
    "JobLocation__PostalCode" : "TA6"
    "CustomField1" : "Permanent",
    "CustomField3" : "FTJOBUKNCSG",
    "WebAdManagerEmail" : "xxxx",
    "JobType" : "Full",
    "ProductID" : "JCPRI0UK"
```

And my Eve schema has been updated accordingly to validate the values of those new key names. Then in the backend I've defined the function below which checks the incoming keys/values and converts them into objects/lists, and also deletes the original __ and && data:

```
import re

def flat_to_complex(items=None, orig=None):

    if type(items) is dict: # inserts of new objects
        if True: # just to force indentation
            objects = {} # hash-based container for each object
            lists   = {} # hash-based container for each list

            for key,value in items.items():
                has_object_wildcard = re.search(r'^([^_]+)__', key, re.IGNORECASE)
                if bool(has_object_wildcard):
                    objects[has_object_wildcard.group(1)] = None
                elif bool(re.search(r'&&', unicode(value))):
                    lists[key] = str(value).split('&&')

            for list_name, this_list in lists.items():
                items[list_name] = this_list

            for obj_name in objects:

                this_obj = {}
                for key,value in items.items():
                    if key.startswith('{s}__'.format(s=obj_name)):
                        match = re.search(r'__(.+)$', key)
                        this_obj[match.group(1)] = value
                        del(items[key])

                objects[obj_name] = this_obj

            for obj_name, this_obj in objects.items():
                items[obj_name] = this_obj

    elif type(items) is list: # updates to existing objects
        for idx in range(len(items)):
            if type(items[idx]) is dict:
                objects = {} # hash-based container for each object
                lists   = {} # hash-based container for each list

                for key,value in items[idx].items():
                    has_object_wildcard = re.search(r'^([^_]+)__', key, re.IGNORECASE)
                    if bool(has_object_wildcard):
                        objects[has_object_wildcard.group(1)] = None
                    elif bool(re.search(r'&&', unicode(value))):
                        lists[key] = str(value).split('&&')

                for list_name, this_list in lists.items():
                    items[idx][list_name] = this_list

                for obj_name in objects:

                    this_obj = {}
                    for key,value in items[idx].items():
                        if key.startswith('{s}__'.format(s=obj_name)):
                            match = re.search(r'__(.+)$', key)
                            this_obj[match.group(1)] = value
                            del(items[idx][key])

                    objects[obj_name] = this_obj

                for obj_name, this_obj in objects.items():
                    items[idx][obj_name] = this_obj
```

And then I just tell Eve to run that function on inserts and updates to that collection:

```
app.on_insert_myendpoint += flat_to_complex
app.on_update_myendpoint += flat_to_complex
```

This achieves what I needed and the resulting record in Mongo is the same as the one from the question above (with _created and _updated attributes). It's obviously not ideal but it gets there, and it's fairly easy to work with once it's in place.